# Missing jar from repo1.maven.org

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

Eclipse is unable to find and download the following jar:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpcomponents-client</artifactId>
<version>4.1.2</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
</dependency>
```

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.httpcomponents|httpclient|4.1.2|jar

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.1.2/httpcomponents-client-4.1.2.jar

Resolved: I dunno where the pom came from.

Is missing.

Answer (score 7):

It's not missing.

That's a pom (Project Object Model) file.

You probably want the httpclient jar.  The pom describes the total project (multiple jar files).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```